# how to get texts of elements with selenium in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I'm tiring to use selenium I headless mode (which works in background and won't open a tab in browser)
my code finds elements but won't show any of texts between tags. any suggestions?

this is the code:

```
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        options.add_argument('--disable-sandbox')

        driver=webdriver.Chrome(Google_Chrome_Webdriver_Path, options=options)

        driver.get(Resource_Path)
        Search_Results=self.search_resorce_page(driver)

        for Search_Result in Search_Results:
            print(Search_Result.text , "\n")
```

Comment: That's because of `Search_Result.text`, instead read the page_source from driver and then parse through what you need, e.g. https://www.browserstack.com/guide/get-html-source-of-web-element-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: thanks .ill be happy if you give me more info's about how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

       .
       .
       .

        driver.get(Resource_Path)
        page_source=driver.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
```